# specific default route for NAT clients different from server itself

Tags: iptables, nat

I have host which have ETH0, ETH1 as WAN interfaces,
and WLAN0 as interface for clients.
default route for host itself its eth0.
And I need to route all nat clients to eth1 (masquerade).
Tried to mark packets with iptables mangle (prerouting) - doesnt help.

Anyone knows how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to mark packets at all. If you just want to route packets based on source address, you can simply do:

```
ip rule add from clients_subnet/mask tab 1 priority 500
ip route add default via second_gateway_ip dev eth1 tab 1
```

This will cause all packets originated from `clients_subnet/mask` to be forwarded via `second_gateway_ip` on eth1 interface. All other traffic will be forwarded via default gateway (given that no other rules are defined).

To do the NAT, you can just do:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: @Yury: You need to provide more details. Edit your question and show us exactly what you have done with any error you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, here is more details:

Here is test environment.
Host has 2 interfaces: ens160 as main WAN, tun-test as WAN interface for NAT clients which connected on ens192.

```
root@ubuntu-16:/# ifconfig
ens160    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:85:f7:ec  
          inet addr:118.211.160.13  Bcast:118.211.160.15  Mask:255.255.255.248
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe85:f7ec/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6454 errors:0 dropped:11 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:743 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:421765 (421.7 KB)  TX bytes:117602 (117.6 KB)

ens192    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:85:c0:c6  
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe85:c0c6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5544 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:342182 (342.1 KB)  TX bytes:3238 (3.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)  TX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)

tun-test  Link encap:IPIP Tunnel  HWaddr   
          inet addr:192.168.100.2  P-t-P:192.168.100.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:336 (336.0 B)  TX bytes:336 (336.0 B)



root@ubuntu-16:/# ip rule
0:  from all lookup local 
500:    from 192.168.1.0/24 lookup 10 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default 

root@ubuntu-16:/# ip route show table 10
default via 192.168.100.1 dev tun-test 


root@ubuntu-16:/# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

root@ubuntu-16:/# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Wed Mar  1 12:13:29 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [135:8626]
:INPUT ACCEPT [110:6610]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8:704]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [7:620]
-A POSTROUTING -o tun-test -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Mar  1 12:13:29 2017
```